# pandas groupby dates by custom date range

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a data frame with a column with dates like this

[image]

now I want to group by the df that every group is starting with the 25 day's in the month and end in the 24 day's of the next month for example:

the first group in my df will be 2021-07-14 and it will contain all the dates from 07-14 until 07-24 and the second group will be 2021-07-25 and it will contain all the dates between 07-25 to 08-24 and so on

Comment: Make an index with date buckets like so `index = pd.DatetimeIndex([ "2021-07-24", "2021-08-24", ... etc])`. Then you can do `grouper = pd.Series(index, index).reindex(df.index, method="ffill")`. Now you can just do `df.groupby(grouper).whatever`. I think this should work but haven't tested.

Comment: @SMeznaric - your solution looks good. The grouper works after grouper = grouper.reset_index(drop=True).

Comment: Did you get an ease way to do this? I want something similar, grouping by last 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easiest to group by year, month, and a binary measure of whether the date is greater than 24 or not.  Using this grouping you can return the group numbers to the original data and then use that for further aggretations.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(start='01-01-2020', freq='d', periods=100)})

df['group'] = df.groupby([df.dates.dt.year,df.dates.dt.month, df.dates.dt.day.gt(24)]).ngroup()
```

Comment: nice idea! but I want the dates after the 24 will be with the group of the next month.

i will try to explain, in your solution for example in July the the first group will be 1-24 but the second will be 25-31 and I want the second group will be 25/7 until 24/8